# How to Imploade Two Arrays in Mysql Query IN Clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have Two Arrays Like `$idarray` and `$idarray1`

I want Combine Two Arrays Like This

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM meeting WHERE meet_id IN('" . implode("','", $idarray) . "')";
```

In this Query I want to add $idarray1

How can i do that

Comment: You do some proper research on the rather trivial topic "how do I combine two arrays in PHP" ...

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 3095156
    [1] => 2864254
    [2] => 2944549
    [3] => 45445787
)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge two array with [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function:

```
$idarray_merged = array_merge($idarray, $idarray1);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM meeting WHERE meet_id IN('" . implode("','", $idarray_merged) . "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use find_in_set to achieve this.

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php